# How to trace specific signals using Verilator?

Tags: trace, verilator

I have a system which I want to trace with Verilator, but using a VCD trace file is highly resource-demanding (hundreds of gigabytes) and time consuming. I changed the trace file type to FST, and the file size is reasonable, but it is still time-consuming. Tracing the whole system is not my goal at the moment because I only want the values of 8 signals, not the 16000 signals of the system.

How can I trace specific signals using Verilator?

Any help or hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Verilator manual has a FAQ for this: [How do I speed up writing large waveform (trace) files?](https://verilator.org/guide/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-speed-up-writing-large-waveform-trace-files)

These are the suggestions (briefly):

1. Delay calling `open`
2. Add the `/*verilator tracing_off*/` metacomment
3. Use the `--trace-depth 1` option
4. FST (which you already tried)
5. Write your trace files to a local solid-state drive, instead of to a network drive